# Python Watchdog: Why is my subprocess called continuously?

Tags: python, subprocess, watchdog, unison

I'm a novice with Python & I'm trying to automate synchronization with my home server with unison. I discovered watchdog & I'm trying to use it, but whenever I run "touch test.txt", the script continuously launches new unison processes. Since the observer is using classes inherited from Queue, I assumed that it should just block after it pops the first event off the  top of the queue. Have I overlooked something here?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class ChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
   def on_any_event(self, event):
      subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/unison", "-batch", "-silent", "-ui", "text",
         "default"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
   observer = Observer()
   observer.schedule(ChangeHandler(), '/home/philip', True)
   observer.start()
   try:
      while True:
         time.sleep(1)
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      observer.stop()
   observer.join()
```

Output:

```
props    <-?-> props      /  props    <-?-> props      Documents  props    <-?-> props      Downloads  props    <-?-> props      /  props    <-?-> props      Documents  props    <-?-> props      Downloads  props    <-?-> props      /  props    <-?-> props      Documents  props    <-?-> props      Downloads  props    <-?-> props      /  props    <-?-> props      Documents  props    <-?-> props      Downloads  props    <-?-> props      /  props    <-?-> props      Documents  props    <-?-> props      Downloads  props    <-?-> props      /  props    <-?-> props      Documents  props    <-?-> props      Downloads
```

Comment: while True:
   time.sleep(1) looks like this will go on until the time itself comes to an end...

Comment: @Jingo or, more likely, until the user presses a 'Ctrl+C' and causes a `KeyboardInterrupt`...

Comment: It took working with pyinotify to finally understand that I'm synchronizing a directory while simultaneously watching that same directory for filesystem events. Of course, i'll get multiple calls unless I suspend the Observer/Notifier when processing an event.

Answer (score 1):

OP sufficiently answered this in a comment:

> It took working with pyinotify to finally understand that I'm synchronizing a directory while simultaneously watching that same directory for filesystem events. Of course, i'll get multiple calls unless I suspend the Observer/Notifier when processing an event.